# Как разбить массив на отдельные массивы?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как разбить массив данных на отдельные массивы, у меня есть массив в формате:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customerName] => 
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test1
                            [1] => Test2
                        )

                    [productPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1223123
                            [1] => 434343
                        )

                    [competitor1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Con1
                            [1] => Con1
                        )

                    [product1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product1
                            [1] => Product1
                        )

                    [competitorPrice1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 213212
                            [1] => 3212311
                        )

                    [competitor2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Con2
                            [1] => Con2
                        )

                    [product2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product2
                            [1] => Product2
                        )

                    [competitorPrice2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 6546566
                            [1] => 454546
                        )

                    [competitor3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Con3
                            [1] => Con3
                        )

                    [product3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product3
                            [1] => Product3
                        )

                    [competitorPrice3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                        )

                    [minPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                        )

                )

            [submit] => Отправить запрос
        )

)
```

Мне нужно в таком формате:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customerName] => 
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test1
                        )

                    [productPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1223123
                        )

                    [competitor1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Con1
                        )

                    [product1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product1
                        )

                    [competitorPrice1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 213212
                        )

                    [competitor2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Con2
                        )

                    [product2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product2
                        )

                    [competitorPrice2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 6546566
                        )

                    [competitor3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Con3
                        )

                    [product3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Product3
                        )

                    [competitorPrice3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [minPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

                [items] => Array
                    (
                        [product] => Array
                            (
                            
                                [0] => Test2
                            )
    
                        [productPrice] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => 434343
                            )
    
                        [competitor1] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => Con1
                            )
    
                        [product1] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => Product1
                            )
    
                        [competitorPrice1] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => 3212311
                            )
    
                        [competitor2] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => Con2
                            )
    
                        [product2] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => Product2
                            )
    
                        [competitorPrice2] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => 454546
                            )
    
                        [competitor3] => Array
                            (
                                
                                [0] => Con3
                            )
    
                        [product3] => Array
                            (
                              
                                [0] => Product3
                            )
    
                        [competitorPrice3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                            )
    
                        [minPrice] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                                [1] => 
                            )
    
                    )

            [submit] => Отправить запрос
        )

)
```

Вот форма

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form class="" action="index.php" method="post" name="">
          <p>
            <input name="customerName" placeholder="Enter customer name">
          </p>
          <table>
            <tr name="myarr">
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Товар</th>
              <th>Цена</th>
              <th>Конкурент №1</th>
              <th>Товар конкурента №1</th>
              <th>Цена конкурента №1</th>
              <th>Конкурент №2</th>
              <th>Товар конкурента №2</th>
              <th>Цена конкурента №2</th>
              <th>Конкурент №3</th>
              <th>Товар конкурента №3</th>
              <th>Цена конкурента №3</th>
              <th>Минимальная цена</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
          </table>
    
          <p>
            <button type="button" onclick="addItem();">
              Add Item
            </button>
          </p>
    
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
          </p>
        </form>
    
        <script>
          var items = 0;
          function addItem() {
            items++;
            var html = "<tr>";
              html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[product][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[productPrice][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[competitor1][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[product1][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[competitorPrice1][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[competitor2][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[product2][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[competitorPrice2][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[competitor3][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[product3][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[competitorPrice3][]'></td>";
              html += "<td><input name='items[minPrice][]'></td>";
            html += "<tr>";
            document.getElementById('tbody').insertRow().innerHTML = html;
          }
        </script>
        <script>
    
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
    
    <?php
    
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $data = array();
        $data[] = $_POST;
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '<pre>';
        $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
        fclose($fp);
      }
    
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Это изначально неверный способ получения массива. И это неверная структура окончательного массива, т.к. это жутко неудобно работать с такими данными в таком формате

Comment: вам надо подумать о том, как изначально получать данные в адекватной структуре, если через БД - это вполне можно сделать. С фронта...да тоже можно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня есть динамичная форма, не получается нужную структуру сделать.


Добавил к вопросу, подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше сделать.

Comment: `products[i]['name']` / `products[i]['price']` / `products[i]['competitor']` , где `i` например счётчик от 0 до длины массива. в итоге на сервере получим сразу ассоциативный массив  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vduIC.png

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Извините, эту форму подсмотрел в интернете, и js я вообще не знаю, создать счетчик это 
var i = 0;
i++;

Но когда я добавляю в форму переменную i у меня не работает добавление новой формы.

Comment: ну что я могу сказать, либо вам предётся подучиваться и всё переделать так, чтобы было нормально, либо вот так дальше продолжать делать ужасные костыли и обходные пути, что в итоге приведёт ещё к большим костылями будет расти как снежный ком, пока в один прекрасный день просто нервная система не выдержит работать с этим ужасом))

Comment: вместо `i` подставьте `items` в текущем коде